# How to view history of curl command executed using Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

Tags: java

We can view bash commands history. It is stored normally in `~/.bash_history`. For the same reason it is not recommended to send a curl request along with certificates and passwords.
But when I execute the same curl command using Runtime class in java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` I don't see this in the bash history.

It makes sense as this is done under the Runtime object and not executed from terminal. So where can I get the history of `curl` when done from Java using Runtime class?

Also is it safe to use Runtime class instead of actually storing certificate in a Trustore and using Https related Java classes?

Note: The certificates will be kept securely in Jenkins anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> How to view history of curl command executed using Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

You didn't run it with bash so, no, it is not in bash history. The answer to your question is OS dependent (and 'linux', in this sense, isn't detailed enough. What kind?) But, for example, as long as the command is running, `ps auxww` will probably show it, with the full command line including the arguments. As long as it is running, the directory representing the status of the process in the `/proc` virtual filesystem definitely lets you see the arguments it was invoked with.

> Also is it safe to use Runtime class instead of actually storing certificate in a Trustore and using Https related Java classes?

That's just not how security works. It's shades of gray, not black and white. However, starting a subprocess for this is definitely a much darker gray (far less safe) than using java itself: As long as it is running, that subprocess arguments can be seen. The version of whatever command you invoke is less controllable (are you going to hash the executable? How would you know that the executable isn't being changed on you? This is of course entirely fine if you know who administrates the box and trust them, but that gets back to that shades of gray thing: If that part doesn't matter, sure, then this part is less problematic (heck, if you are the only one with an ssh login to this box, and only run trusted software, you can write the password across 50 files with global readability all over the file system and it wouldn't matter - and yet nobody is going to go on record and just make a blanket statement that this is 'safe'!).

Comment: I agree on this. We are using a cloud enterprise Jenkins so if any security breach, the code would be the last part for interrogation.